# Why does grep require a backslash before a plus sign to treat the plus sign as a quantifier?

Tags: grep, regex

I wanted to play a bit with a `grep` command using regular expressions and found out that they behave differently from what I expected. For example, consider a file `temp` with the following content

```
helloworld 
hello_world
hello world
hello how are you world
hello wor   ld
hello_*_..world 
helloEworld
```

when I run

```
grep 'hello.*world' temp
```

it returns

```
helloworld 
hello_world
hello world
hello how are you world
hello_*_..world 
helloEworld
```

as expected. But when I run

```
grep 'hello.+world' temp
```

it returns nothing... Though when I add `\` before `+`

```
grep 'hello.\+world' temp
```

it returns the correct output

```
hello_world
hello world
hello how are you world
hello_*_..world 
helloEworld
```

while adding `\`  before `*` in the previous command and running

```
grep 'hello.\*world' temp
```

returns nothing...

Why doesn't the `grep 'hello.+world' temp` command work without the `\`?

Why is it exactly the opposite for `*`?

When should I use `\`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various classes of regular expressions that GNU `grep` supports:

- Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) - the default. Doesn't support `+` directly, but does support `*`. You can make `+` make sense when you escape it `\+`. From [GNU grep documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html):

  ```
  In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ‘?’, ‘+’, ‘{’, ‘|’,
  ‘(’, and ‘)’ lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed
  versions ‘\?’, ‘\+’, ‘\{’, ‘\|’, ‘\(’, and ‘\)’.
  ```
- Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) - the option `-E` enables this. Supports both `+` and `*` directly.
- Perl-compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) - the `-P` option enables PCRE. Supports syntax similar to Perl's, such as lookaheads and lookbehinds.

BRE and ERE are usually [POSIX-defined standard classes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), so you should find them on any `grep` which aspires to POSIX compatibility, and expect to behave similarly.